# Simple DFA using the State Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I've been getting to grips with some Monads in Haskell recently, and to get some practice I plucked a Mealy Machine out of thin air and decided to implement it using the State Monad (it's a simple machine and a simple implementation, don't worry).

- The input is a string of characters from `+`, `-`, `n`, `e`.

  - `+`, "plus". Output a `1`,
  - `-`, "minus". Output a `-1`.
  - `n`, "toggle negated". Until "toggled off", flip the sign of the output from `+` or `-`.
  - `e`, "toggle enabled". Until "toggled back on", output `0` from `+` or `-`.
- The output is just a sequence of the same length as the input, containing `1`, `0`, and `-1`s as outputted by the DFA. In the code below, the output is actually the sum of this sequence, acting as a quick checksum. All states are accepting states.

For example, an input of `+-n+-e+e+` would result in `[1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1]`.

To unambiguously define the behaviour, here's a pretty messy state transition diagram:

[image]

<sup>If "posate" (as the opposite of negate) isn't a word already, it is now!
The transitions are labelled with the "english name", the symbol used to represent this transition, and the "output" from the machine. All states are accepting states, I left out the conventional double rings.</sup>

---

At last, the code:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy
import Control.Monad (foldM)

data Input = Plus | Minus | ToggleNegate | ToggleEnabled
type Emission = Integer
type Accum = [Emission]
type Output = [Emission]
type Negated = Bool
type Enabled = Bool

toInput :: Char -> Input
toInput '+' = Plus
toInput '-' = Minus
toInput 'n' = ToggleNegate
toInput 'e' = ToggleEnabled
toInput  _  = error "Invalid input representation"

-- Determine new state of state machine along with transition emission
step :: (Negated, Enabled, Input) -> (Negated, Enabled, Emission)
step (n, e, ToggleNegate)  = (not n, e, 0)
step (n, e, ToggleEnabled) = (n, not e, 0)
step (n, False, i)         = (n, False, 0)
step (n, e, Plus)          = (n, e, if n then -1 else  1)
step (n, e, Minus)         = (n, e, if n then  1 else -1)

-- Helper function for "evaluate"'s foldM
mapEmissions :: Accum -> Input -> State (Negated, Enabled) Output
mapEmissions accum input = do
    (negated, enabled) <- get
    let (negated', enabled', emission) = step (negated, enabled, input)
    put (negated', enabled')
    return (accum ++ [emission])

-- Process an input string and return the result
-- (False, True) is the start state: (not negated, enabled)
evaluate :: [Input] -> Output
evaluate inputs = evalState (foldM mapEmissions [] inputs) (False, True)


-- Convenience function for output formatting
shouldEqual :: String -> Integer -> IO ()
shouldEqual input expected = do
    let actual = (sum . evaluate . map toInput) input
    putStrLn $ "Expected " ++ show expected ++ ", got " ++ show actual ++ ": " ++ input

main :: IO ()
main = do
    "+-n--n" `shouldEqual` 2
    "+e----e++" `shouldEqual` 3
    "-n++e++e--+-n++" `shouldEqual` 1
```

[Code online here](https://ideone.com/r1jPU6).

---

I'm happy to hear **any and all critiques and advice**, but in particular:

- Am I using the State monad idiomatically? Can I write any bits of code more elegantly?
- Is this an appropriate use for this monad? This isn't a particularly complex task, but I feel like it makes passing around the DFA's state simpler.

Thanks for taking the time to read, and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use `traverse` instead of `foldM` + accumulate

In a fold, you usually use a function that reduces (or folds) your input into a single result. You, on the other hand, use `fold mapEmissions` to create a list from an input list. Both lists will have the same number of elements. That's not a fold. That's a map.

So first of all, let's use `traverse` instead of `foldM`:

```
evaluate :: [Input] -> Output
evaluate inputs = evalState (traverse emit inputs) (False, True)
```

Next, let's figure out how `emit` should look like:

```
emit :: Input -> State (Negated, Enabled) Emission
emit input = do
    (negated, enabled) <- get
    let (negated', enabled', emission) = step (negated, enabled, input)
    put (negated', enabled')
    return emission
```

Almost the same as `mapEmission`, and we can use `emit` to implement `mapEmission`:

```
mapEmission accum input = (accum ++) <$> emit input
```

Therefore, we should really replace the `foldM` by `traverse`.

## Consider already existing interfaces

`step` can be rewritten with another interface that fits the [`state`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:state) interface:

```
type MMState = (Negated, Enabled) --  Mealy Machine State

step :: Input -> MMState -> (MMState, Emission)
step ToggleNegate  (n, e)     = ((not n, e    ), 0)
step ToggleEnabled (n, e)     = ((    n, not e), 0)
step _             (n, False) = ((n,     False), 0)
step Plus          (n, e)     = ((n,     e    ), if n then -1 else  1)
step Minus         (n, e)     = ((n,     e    ), if n then  1 else -1)
```

This makes `emit` even easier:

```
emit :: Input -> State MMState Emission
emit input = state (step input)
```

Note that `MMState` makes it easier to change the other types, as there is less repetition.

It's completely up to you to write `step` like this, though.

## Encapsulate possible errors in the type (if possible)

In `toInput` consider `Maybe Input` or `Either String Input` instead of `error`:

```
toInput :: Char -> Either String Input
toInput '+' = pure Plus
toInput '-' = pure Minus
toInput 'n' = pure ToggleNegate
toInput 'e' = pure ToggleEnabled
toInput  c  = Left $ "Unrecognised character: " ++ [c]
```

## Use `Int` instead of `Integer` if the values are small

Instead of `Integer` we should use `Int` as `Emission`. `Integer` can be arbitrarily large, but your output values are either `-1`, `0` or `1`. `Int` is much more suitable for that.

## Other comments

Other than that, well done. You followed good practice by including type signatures, and your code is easy to read and to follow. The only real hurdle was `foldM` instead of `traverse`.

However, your *single* instruction type is called `Input`, whereas your *complete* output type is called `Output`. That naming is somewhat unbalanced.

---

Overall, we end up with:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy

data Input = Plus | Minus | ToggleNegate | ToggleEnabled
type Emission = Int
type Output = [Emission]
type Negated = Bool
type Enabled = Bool
type MMState = (Negated, Enabled) --  Mealy Machine State

toInput :: Char -> Either String Input
toInput '+' = pure Plus
toInput '-' = pure Minus
toInput 'n' = pure ToggleNegate
toInput 'e' = pure ToggleEnabled
toInput  c  = Left $ "Unrecognised character: " ++ [c]

step :: Input -> MMState -> (MMState, Emission)
step ToggleNegate  (n, e)     = ((not n, e),     0)
step ToggleEnabled (n, e)     = ((    n, not e), 0)
step _             (n, False) = ((n,     False), 0)
step Plus          (n, e)     = ((n,     e),     if n then -1 else  1)
step Minus         (n, e)     = ((n,     e),     if n then  1 else -1)

emit :: Input -> State MMState Emission
emit input = state (step input)

evaluate :: [Input] -> Output
evaluate inputs = evalState (traverse emit inputs) (False, True)
```

By the way, we can now use `emit` on any traversable, so we could relax `evaluate`'s type to

```
evaluate :: Traversable t => t Input -> t Emission
evaluate inputs = evalState (traverse emit inputs) (False, True)
```

But that's up to you.

Comment: Whoops, I'd forgotten that `mapM` also mapped the monad instance through the list, I'd assumed it processed each element independently... I've not read up on applicatives yet, but how you're using them here is a major incentive to do so! The new `step` function is really good too, and some day I'll get out of the bad habit of just `error`'ing everything. Thank you for the really thorough review that taught me new things!

Comment: @hnefatl nowadays `mapM = traverse`, since every Monad is also an Applicative. So if you know `mapM`, you already know `traverse`.

Comment: I would eliminate `Input` and make `step`'s type signature `Char -> StateT MMState (Either String) Emission`, then use `lens` to write lines such as `step 'n' = (_1 %= not) $> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good to me.

The only thing I'd be wary of is the `return (accum ++ [emission])` which means building the ouput will have complexity `O(n²)` where `n` is the size of the output. To remedy that, you could store the output in reversed order i.e. have `return (emission : accum)` instead and call `reverse` in `evaluate`.

You could also decide to structure this outputting mechanism as a [`Writer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#t:WriterT) in which case you probably want to use the `Endo [a]` monoid aka [Difference Lists](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list) for the same efficiency reasons.

Comment: Or use `mapM`/`traverse` instead of `foldM`.

Comment: I was under the impression that a sequence of appends in Haskell was only more `O(n)` if the list is forced to be evaluated during the sequence, as it's lazy. To use `Writer` along with `State` I'd need a monad transformer, right? I've not yet read up on those.

Comment: @hnefatl A sequence of appends is fine if you use `a ++ b ++ c ++ d = a ++ (b ++ (c ++ d))`. But due to the fold, we end up with `((a ++ b) ++ c) ++ d`. Remember that `(x:xs) ++ ys = x : xs ++ ys` and you can see why the latter is a problem (we need to inspect `a` several times).